# CSS height 100% when inner childs have float

Tags: css, height

I have a basic structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

where `.sidebar` and `.content` have `float: left`

I've seen too many answers on S.O. and they all work ONLY IF `.content` is not bigger than the screen itself. To illustrate my problem i have this two examples

http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/h35vc/2/ (small content)
http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/56C9v/1/ (big content)

as you can see, when the `.content` div is too big the `height:100%` on the container doesn't work anymore.

In both cases, the gray div should be 100% height. My guess is that the browser calculates the window height before floating the elements.

Is it possible to solve this using only CSS? (i could do it with JS but it just seems too dirty)

Comment: you add float:left to .content and it holds it all

Comment: I don't think its particularly clear what you're looking for.  You say the gray div should be 100% height, but in both those cases it is 100% of the height of its parent, which is the viewport.  Child nodes have no bearing on the height attribute. When you set `height: 100%`, it means "this should be the same height as its nearest positioned ancestor" What kind of layout are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `height` attribute

```
.container{
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 20px;
    //no height declared
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/56C9v/7/

If you want the container to always occupy 100% then set min-height: 100% eg

```
.container{
        background-color: #999;
        padding: 20px;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: you're the man!... min-height in container... didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want the container/content to ever go beyond 100% of the screen height.

You can accomplish this by adding: `overflow:hidden;` to your `container` stylesheet.

For more information about the overflow property, see: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: yeah, actually, this would be better. Will still need to clear the floats, but I agree with Adam

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the heights and put `overflow:auto` on your container.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/56C9v/5/)** (large)

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h35vc/4/)** (small)

Comment: it wont work if the content is not big enough http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/jLHTa/.. I need the container to be 100%

Comment: What doesn't work? I don't see what point you're trying to make with the last fiddle you posted.

Comment: the gray area should fill the window's height... in your second fiddle, the gray area is only about 80% of the window's height

Comment: my answer eradicates this problem with `min-height: 100%`

Comment: What browser are you using? In my second example the gray area fills the full height.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the container to always be 100% of the height of the document and the floats to also stretch down but not increase the height of the container.

Margins on the body make it exceed 100% height, so to eliminate that...

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Your container has padding which will exceed 100% height, so we use the new `border-box`...

```
.container{
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then set the floats to 100% height and handle text overflowing with a scroll bar...

```
.sidebar, .content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I think this is what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/56C9v/10/

Comment: thxs but not really... i didnt wanted the scroll on container :P